# How to create an Http Request to another Server (URI) and call it synchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.net MVC3 application. In one of my controllers there is a action for sending SMS to some Users of our application. Now according to our SMS provider, he will need a http request to his server (say http://www.sms-sender-server.com). There are a number of request parameters that will be appended to this URI. A request then needs to be send to the above URI with request parameters and the sms server will send Status Code(response) back indicating whether sms sending failed or succeeded. I am not sure how we create such a request in ASP.net (or C# if that seems logical). If anyone can put me in right direction, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). This is simpler to use than WebRequest(and its derivatives). And internally it uses WebRequest too.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx) class. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx) has a sample:

```
// Create a new 'Uri' object with the specified string.
Uri myUri =new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
// Create a new request to the above mentioned URL. 
WebRequest myWebRequest= WebRequest.Create(myUri);
// Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
WebResponse myWebResponse= myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Check the `StatusCode` property of the `WebResponse` object for the returned status from the SMS provider.

Comment: WebRequest (Or HttpWebRequest) seems to be quite a fit for my scenario. However, I was wondering why it doesn't have a name/value parameters for constructing its QueryString like the WebClient has (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.querystring.aspx). Will I have to build query string manually without the help of Name/Value pairs ?

Comment: Yes you will - the answer is because `WebRequest` is generally a lower level implementation than `WebClient` so, while you have more control, you get less work done for you. But since you're interested in the status code rather than the actual response, it makes sense to go for `WebRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [HttpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know the title of the question specifically asks about synchronous calls but you might really want to look into the Async controllers for 3rd party off network requests.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.98).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)